# Linux permissions executing script

Tags: linux, permissions, cron, sudo

Question is about sudo&cron
I have 2 servers:

srv0
 
 - I auth by .ppk and login name 
 
- I run by hand simple .py script with sudo.
 
- Script runs command to webservice and prints to file time+returned datas(tuple).
It also runs well by cron, which was the aim

srv1 diff
 
- I auth by root password
 
- I can run script by hand without sudo and it works well
 
- Cron runs it well, but prints to file just time. It didn't execute command... It sends empy body message to /var/spool/mail/root

Extras:

- /home/monitors, 2 files(.py, log) are 777 at both servers

whats the problem with cron at srv1? Maybe in fileOpen?

```
import string
import commands
import time

namesStr ='currtime;wrs-checklist-create;wrs-checklist-delete;wrs-checklist-getall;wrs-checklist-getone;wrs-checklist-update;wrs-photo-queue;wrs-shop-getall;wrs-template-getall;wrs-xauth-authenticate;'

getmess = commands.getstatusoutput('rabbitmqctl list_queues messages')
getmess = list(getmess[1].split('\n'))

messStr = ''
nixtime = str(int(time.time()))

for mess in getmess:
        messStr += mess + ';'

logQue = open('/home/monitors/logQue', 'a')
print >> logQue, nixtime + messStr
logQue.close()
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the crontab, before you command, add . $HOME/.bash_profile. For example:

0 5 * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command/to/run

Cron knows nothing about your shell; it is started by the system, so it has a minimal environment. If you want anything, you need to have that brought in yourself.

**OR**

just change line

getmess = commands.getstatusoutput('**rabbitmqctl** list_queues messages')

to

getmess = commands.getstatusoutput('**/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl** list_queues messages')

**which rabbitmqctl** helps you find path to rabbitmqctl

PS

Sorry for my English (:

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!